# Ist „Mal“ als Füllwort regionaler Dialekt?

Tags: dialect, regional

Ist das Wort „mal“ als Entschärfung des Imperativs, also „Komm mal her.“ statt „Komm bitte her.“ oder gar „Komm her.“ regionaler Dialekt (vllt. HH/SH), oder durchaus teil des deutschen Sprachgebrauchs? Gibt es eine Alternative?

Comment: Ich würde auf überregionalen Sprachgebrauch tippen. Kannst Du bitte erläutern, was genau die Alternative leisten soll? (z.B.: soll der Tonfall ähnlich bleiben oder strenger/weniger streng sein?)

Comment: Eine Alternative suche ich, weil mir aufgefallen ist, dass ich Mal für mein Empfinden zu oft verwende.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/node/136320/revision/136356) schreibt über die Partikel *einmal*: *wirkt verstärkend in Aussagen, Fragen und Aufforderungen* und nennt das Beispiel *komm doch einmal her!* Das [WDG](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wdg/einmal) schreibt:

> III. *unbetont; partikelhaft, ohne eigentliche Bedeutung; intensiviert und belebt den Satz; umg. gekürzt zu* mal
>   […]
>   5. *verstärkt den Imperativsatz umg.* doch: denke dir e.!; höre e. her!; komm doch e. her!; sei doch e. so gut und reiche mir die Butter!; komm erst e. herein!; lege (doch) erst e. ab!;

Und schließlich das [DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=einmal) (unter B.3; die Kürzung zu *mal* wird unter B.10 behandelt):

> *nach dem imp. hat* einmal *den bittenden, zurufenden, aufmunternden sinn des lat.* heus *und* quaeso *(vgl.* DWB bald 1, 1081): hör einmal! komm einmal her! setze dich einmal! denke dir einmal! *wie wir auch* doch *verwenden*: höre doch! komm doch her! setze dich doch! *oder beide wörter häufen*: höre doch einmal *u.s.w.*

Einen Hinweis auf regionalen Sprachgebrauch sehe ich nicht. Die triviale Alternative zu *mal* wäre *einmal*. Vielleicht, je nach Empfinden, auch *bitte* oder *doch*. (Gegen die Ersetzbarkeit von *mal* durch *doch* und *bitte* spricht natürlich, daß alle drei zusammen auftreten können: *Komm doch mal bitte her!*)

Answer (score 1):

Eigene Beobachtung, keine Quellen.

<sub>Zunächst: "Komm mal her" statt "Komm Mal her."</sub>

Überall in Deutschland angetroffen (=keine Beobachtung in A, CH), hängt am Duktus der Person und am Tonfall / dem Einsatzzweck.

Andere beobachtete Varianten (Update: Ergänzung aus den Kommentaren):

- "Komm mal bitte her."
- "Herkommen!"
- "Kannst Du mal herkommen?" (als Frage formuliert und als Aussagesatz gemeint)
- "Kannst Du bitte herkommen?" (als höfliche Langform)
- "Kommst Du mal?"

[Da der Ton die Musik macht](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=Der%20Ton%20macht%20die%20Musik&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou), sehe ich es als möglich, mit und ohne "bitte" es freundlich oder unwirsch klingen zu lassen. Da ich erwarte, diesen Satz zwischen zwei Menschen zu hören, die sich ausreichend gut kennen (und duzen), ist ein "bitte" durchaus mit der Bedeutung, den anderen überstimmen zu müssen - womit es eher weniger freundlich wird. Denn es ist kein "Kann ich bitte die Butter haben", das eigentliche Ziel des Hinkommens ist in der Aufforderung noch unklar.

Comment: In meinem persönlichen Umfeld (BaWü) wird es auch durchgehend benutzt. Kann aber nichts dazu sagen, wie es damit im Rest von D aussieht...

Comment: Interessanterweise klingt für mich "Kannst du bitte herkommen" grob und scharf (unwirsch), während "Kannst du mal herkommen" freundlich und vorsichtig klingt. Um "Kannst du bitte herkommen" die Schärfe zu nehmen, müsste man mindestens noch Konjunktiv einsetzen: "Könntest du bitte herkommen", aber selbst das hilft nicht viel, und auch "Könntest du bitte mal herkommen" klingt nicht viel besser. Kurz gesagt: Sobald das "bitte" dabei ist, klingt es förmlich und dadurch unfreundlich. Am sanftesten klingt für mich: "Kommst du mal?".

Comment: Ja, das Gefühl, dass der Imprativ ohne „mal“ grob und scharf wirkt habe ich auch, deswegen die Benutzung. Allerdings habe ich auch das Gefühl, dass ich das Wort dadurch zu häufig benutze.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: ja und nein: zunächst denke ich, dass der Satz ja sehr informell ist und beide eine enge Beziehung haben - da in eine "dringende" Aufforderung ein "Bitte" einsetzen zeigt, dass das Gegenüber "überstimmt" werden muss. Andererseits kann ich mit der Betonung jede (außer vielleicht "Herkommen!") freundlich und auch unwirsch klingen lassen. Spontan vermute ich, dass das eingefügte "bitte" durchschnittlich mehr im unwirschen Ton verwendet wird.